# Geocode function fails for valid location data and within query limit

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

I want to use `ggmap::geocode()` to get the coordinates for different locations but the call seems to fail unexpectedly for unknown reasons. I'm not over the query limit as seen in below attempts and the address I'm trying to geocode is valid.

```
> geocodeQueryCheck()
2494 geocoding queries remaining.
> geocode("McGill University Montreal", output = "latlon")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=McGill%20University%20Montreal&sensor=false
  lon lat
1  NA  NA
Warning message:
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "McGill University Montreal" 
> geocode("McGill University Montreal", output = "latlon")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=McGill%20University%20Montreal&sensor=false
        lon      lat
1 -73.57715 45.50478
> geocodeQueryCheck()
2492 geocoding queries remaining.
> paste(geocode("McGill University Montreal", output = "latlon"), collapse = " ")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=McGill%20University%20Montreal&sensor=false
[1] "NA NA"
Warning message:
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "McGill University Montreal" 
> paste(geocode("McGill University Montreal", output = "latlon"), collapse = " ")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=McGill%20University%20Montreal&sensor=false
[1] "-73.5771511 45.5047847"
```

Comment: It's written `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. Why do you think you're not over query limits? Google not only has a maximum of queries per 24h but also per second. (See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits?) So `Sys.sleep(1)` between queries might do the trick..

Comment: In the example, I ran `geocodeQueryCheck()` after each call which clearly shows I have over 2400 queries remaining before I reach the limit. The unsuccessful attempts are counted as evidenced by the decreasing number of remaining queries.

Comment: I think this is a bug in `ggmap` and have tolerated it to date and just repeated failed queries. Other packages are available now like `library(googleway)` which offer geocoding functions. Which might be better, but I haven't tested them yet, but promised myself for my next geocoding project I would

Comment: @Nate I'll try `googleway`. @symbolrush you're right about the time between queries and it's not clear in the above example but I waited over a second before each attempt.